# Need better explanation of a mathematical/programming problem?

Tags: math

The problem is:

> For a prime number p the set of co-primes less than or equal to it is given by {1,2,3,4,...p-1} .
>
> We define f(x,p) 0 < x < p = 1 if and only if all the numbers from 1 to p-1 can be written as a power of x in modulo-p arithmetic .
>
> Let n be the largest 12-digit prime number . Find the product of all integers j less than n such that f(j,n)=1, in modulo-n arithmetic

Can anyone give me a better explanation?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Also, how does this relate to programming?

Comment: Don't make me scroll horizontally

Comment: David: This is a problem in a programming competition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try asking this over on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know it existed.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that you're having trouble understanding what the question is asking you to do.

First, the function f must be defined. It needs to return 1 "if and only if all the numbers from 1 to p-1 can be written as a power of x in modulo-p arithmetic". That is, in pseudo-code:

```
for i from 1 to p-1
   if (for some n, (x^n)%p != i%p) return 0
end for
return 1
```

If any of those numbers `i` can't be written as `x^n` for some `n`, then we don't return 1. If they all work, then we return 1.

Last, we're looking for the product of all those `j`s. So, again, in pseudo-code:

```
let p = 1
for j from 1 to n
    if (f(j,n)==1)  p = p*j
end for
return p%n
```

We only multiply in the `j` if `f(j,n)` is `1`, as requested. Does that make sense? Is there a specific part of the question you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

really bad psuedocode for definition purposes -- this is not the correct code to do this

```
function answerToQuestion()
  answer = 1
  n = getLargest12DigitPrime()
  for j = 1 to n-1
      if (f(j,n) == 1)
         answer *= j

  return answer
end function

function f(j, n)
  for x=1 to n-1
     if not canBeWrittenAsPowerOfJModuloN(x, j, n)
         return 0
  return 1
end function
```